# AWK compare to produce desired merged output

Tags: awk

I am attempting to use AWK to compare two csv files and generate a merged output based on the compare results. Both files have a matched value and I can get it to display the desired value in data2 column ($2) with the match value (data1-$1 data2-$4) but what I want is data2-$2 and data1-$2. Looking to understand how to make that happen.

data1.csv

```
dt-101,willow
dt-102,dogwood
dt-103b,redbud
dt-103a,plum
dt-104,cedar
ls-47,oak
ls-47a,pinoak
ls-47b,liveoak
```

data2.csv

```
4001,00:00:00:01,eric,dt-101
4002,00:00:00:02,paul,dt-101
4003,00:00:00:03,steve,dt-103b
4004,00:00:00:04,mike,dt-104
4005,00:00:00:05,dave,ls-47b
4006,00:00:00:06,alex,dt-102
4007,00:00:00:07,adam,ls-47a
```

Here is the string i am using

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {print $2,a[$4]}' data1.csv data2.csv
```

Here is what I get

```
00:00:00:01,dt-101
00:00:00:02,dt-101
00:00:00:03,dt-103b
00:00:00:04,dt-104
00:00:00:05,ls-47b
00:00:00:06,dt-102
00:00:00:07,ls-47a
```

But what I want is

```
00:00:00:01,willow
00:00:00:02,willow
00:00:00:03,redbud
00:00:00:04,cedar
00:00:00:05,liveoak
00:00:00:06,dogwood
00:00:00:07,pinoak
```

Comment: Not sure how you are getting the stated output (since you don't seem to be assigning *any* values to the array elements)  - it looks like you just need to assign `a[$1]=$2` i.e. `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $2,a[$4]}' data1.csv data2.csv`

Comment: Ah I had a[$1] = $1, missed that above some how.  Changing to $2 fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $2,a[$4]}' data1.csv data2.csv

#Output

[GC@GC awk]$ ls
data1.csv  data2.csv
[GC@GC awk]$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $2,a[$4]}' data1.csv data2.csv
00:00:00:01,willow
00:00:00:02,willow
00:00:00:03,redbud
00:00:00:04,cedar
00:00:00:05,liveoak
00:00:00:06,dogwood
00:00:00:07,pinoak
[GC@GC awk]$
```